# Custom actions in rails controller with restful actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm having some trouble with using creating my own actions inside a controller I generated using the scaffold.

I understand everything maps to the restful actions but I'm building a user controller where users can login/logout, etc but when I created the action and declared it in the routes.rb I get this error when I visit users/login

```
Couldn't find User with id=login
```

It tries to use login as a ID parameter instead of using it as an action.

Routes.rb

```
match 'users/login' => 'users#login'
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the routes so if anybody could help me that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I think your routes is calling users#show instead of users#login. So you have to change 'users/login' to some other url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume your `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
resources :users
match 'users/login' => 'users#login'
```

The problem is that Rails uses the first route that matches. From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a `resources :photos` above a `get 'photos/poll'` the `show` action’s route for the `resources` line will be matched before the `get` line. To fix this, move the `get` line **above** the `resources` line so that it is matched first.

So either define your custom route *before* `resources :users`:

```
match 'users/login' => 'users#login'
resources :users
```

…or use this syntax for [adding more RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'login'
  end
end
```

To see the existing routes (and their order) run [`rake routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake) from the command line.