# Rails 3: mixing "generic" controller routes with standard resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got a set of routes that looks like this:

```
resources :placements do
  match '/foo' => "placements#foo"
  match '/bar' => "placements#bar"
end
```

This produces routes that behave like you would expect:

```
/placements/1234/foo
/placements/1234/bar
```

However, I also need "generic" routes for a few methods that do not need an individual placement. So, I build a routes block that looks like this:

```
resources :placements do
  match '/foo' => "placements#foo"
  match '/bar' => "placements#bar"
end
match '/placements/baz' => "placements#baz"
```

If I `rake routes`, I get a route that looks good:

```
/placements/baz
```

Note the lack of an id.  However, if I try to *visit* that route, Rails tries to call the `show` method on the controller instead, as if "baz" was an ID, instead of a method name.  How can I build a routing structure that gives me what I am after, without having to change the first segment of my route (`placements`), to something else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356453/custom-actions-in-rails-controller-with-restful-actions/11358656#11358656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the second route over the `resources` block ie,

```
match '/placements/baz' => "placements#baz"
resources :placements, :id => /\d+/ do
  match '/foo' => "placements#foo"
  match '/bar' => "placements#bar"
end
```

or add a regex for the `id` in `resources`, ie something like:

```
resources :placements, :id => /\d+/ do
  match '/foo' => "placements#foo"
  match '/bar' => "placements#bar"
end
match '/placements/baz' => "placements#baz"
```